# SQL Server - return 0 or null if value of another column is same as another row

Tags: sql-server

View A:

```
CLASS     DESCR       MEETING TIMES                             PRICE
----------------------------------------------------------------------
CLASS_1   Cooking     Mon-Fri, 4-5 10/1/2018 - 10/10/2018       20.00
CLASS_1   Cooking     Tue-Thur, 6-7 10/11/2018 - 10/13/2018     20.00
```

I want result set to be:

```
CLASS     DESCR       MEETING TIMES                             PRICE
---------------------------------------------------------------------
CLASS_1   Cooking     Mon-Fri, 4-5 10/1/2018 - 10/10/2018       20.00
CLASS_1   Cooking     Tue-Thur, 6-7 10/11/2018 - 10/13/2018     0 or null
```

I have a report that shows both rows, and so it looks like they're both $20.00 when in fact they're the same class and should only be a total of $20.00, not $40.00.

Maybe I'm overthinking?

But is there an easier way to return 0 or null for Price if the value of CLASS is found in another row in the returned set... other than case statements with subselect, etc?

Comment: I would fix this in the report, not the sql.

Comment: If, for some reason, you must fix this in the SQL, the version of SQL Server you are using would be important. If you are using SQL Server 2012 or later, you should take a look at the LAG function.

Comment: I did find a way to do this but realized it's not what I wanted, nor is this really where the problem is. 
I think the problem is that I have the price at the class level, but Meeting Times is really another level and I'm trying to put it in the same view, which doesn't work if I need the results in a single data set.

So I ended up using XML Path to concatenate the meeting times in the view so that it's all one level.

Comment: @user3760332 totally agree here. Price should exist in a seperate table. table `class` with `price` and table `classtimes` with this other info in it.